# "Mage registry key "product" already exists" Error When Trying To Mass Delete Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, mage

I have this strange error when I'm trying to mass delete products from Magento admin (catalog>manage products). When i select multiple products and choose Delete option from "Actions menu it deletes only first product from selected list and gives me error "Mage registry key "product" already exists".

Any ideas what could be causing it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mage::unregister($key)` function to resolve the registry error if you know the key.

Comment: The key is "product" as in the error message. So do a full text search for `Mage::register('product'` and you'll probably have the right code part where to insert the unregister code.